# Highlighting a row based on 3 columns of independent criteria

Tags: excel

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to make this work.  I'm creating Excel 2010 Windows 7 spreadsheet based on a school-wide benchmark that needs to specifically include 3 criteria: grade level K-5, subject - Math or Reading, and percentage score.  I want to use  3 or 4 colors (red, yellow, green, and hopefully a 4th color of blue) to show an "if-then" statement that will also highlight the entire row in a specific color to indicate how the child did on a benchmark.

So the color needs to be based on grade level, subject, and the percent.  All three criteria are independent from each other, so 60% in Math for a 1st grader would be yellow, but 60% for a 2nd grader in Reading may be green. Or 60% in Math for a 1st grader may be yellow, but 60% in Reading may be green.  All 3 criteria are independent from the rest.  I hope I explained that correctly.

For example:  if a student in grade level 4 has a score of greater or equal to 90%, then the entire row is highlighted in green.  So I need it to include a cell for 3 columns:  grade level (number), subject (word), and score by percent (number with %).  If a student in 3rd grade received a score of 45% in Reading, then the entire row in highlighted in red.

I've been playing around with Conditional Formatting, but I can't seem to find exactly how to make all this work.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated as I'm pulling out my hair trying to play around with this and failing miserably.  My success would put me in the red right now!

Thank you

Comment: If you're trying to color code every combination of grade and subject and then score that's 6 grades * 2 subjects * however many grade brackets you're looking at. So, at least 12 colors before the grade brackets if you want them to be uniquely highlighted. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

What have you achieved already?

Do you have some lookup tables, where you can finds scores, specific for the subject, grade?

Maybe you can add a (hidden) column to the sheet where you put the result of the lookup formula and base styling on that result.

Otherwise you could define a function/macro in VBA that returns a color string, or even do the coloring.